# Can't load URL of file from hard drive in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, file, url

This is part of my university preparation for interactive systems and I an really stuck at this very moment. I am making a reservations app.

I have this problem with my javascript app as it does not want to load a `.json` file from my computer and it just prompts me that it cannot load it.

Is there anything I can do for it? What am I doing wrong?

```
....
     //Get reservations data from file
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "d:\Proj\TMP\reservations.json", 
        success: function(reservations)
        {
          $currentReservations = reservations;
           $.each(reservations, function(i, reservation)
....
```

Thank you guys in advance, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Is the file on a local machine or is it hosted on a server?

Comment: It is local currently. Later it shall be put into a server. Hopefully.

Comment: Then use FireFox and add `file:///` protocol part to the URL. And do not use backslashes in the path, use `/` instead.

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work. This is the reason I decided to come here as I really had no idea what is going wrong. On some other examples it did work with url:

Comment: It works for sure, when you're doing it correctly, notice the last notification in my previous comment too. The Backslash in JS string is an escaping character, the path in your code is converted to `d:ProjTMP<CarriageReturn>reservations.json`.

Comment: file: "d:ProjTMP<CarriageReturn>reservations.json",
--
I tried it like this and it didn't work.
Before I had it working with other files but not any longer...

Comment: Likely violates [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Also, a url can not begin with "d:\"  See section 4:URLs of [URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: Umh ... That was an example of an incorrect URL, was not worth trying = ). A correct URL would be `file://D:/Proj/TMP/reservations.json`, and don't forget, that this will work in FireFox only.

Comment: I am using firefox but it still does not work. What am I doing so bloody wrong? Everything was going ever so well, until I got to this part.

Comment: Maybe it's jQuery? You could try with the native `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Nothing works so far. This is desperate I will begin it anew from scratch now.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON runs async

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
});
```

Comment: The problem I have with this is that I am unable to get the path set properly I think. This serves no other purpose but reading a file with no path attached.